# Telnet server returning strange characters

Tags: java, character, telnet

I made this program for a school, and it involves a telnet server. When I run it, it returnes strange characters such as `ÿûÿû`. Here is the output:

```
Client connected with the IP /127.0.0.1
Client /127.0.0.1 has entered the username ÿûÿû ÿûÿû'ÿýÿûÿýdcole.
```

My code:

```
Socket client = serv.accept();

InetAddress clientip = client.getInetAddress();

out("Client connected with the IP " + clientip);

InputStream clientinput = client.getInputStream();
OutputStream clientoutput = client.getOutputStream();

Scanner in = new Scanner(clientinput);
clientoutput.write("Please enter your username: ".getBytes());

String username = in.nextLine();
out("Client " + clientip + " has entered the username " + username + ".");

String pass = "Please enter the password for " + username + ": ";
clientoutput.write(pass.getBytes());

String password = in.nextLine();

if (username.equals("dcole") && password.equals("test")) {
    clientoutput.write("\r\nCorrect password!".getBytes());
} else {
    clientoutput.write("\r\nIncorrect password!".getBytes());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe there is some dirty information in your `InputStream` from when you created the `Socket`. Are you able to clean out the data before you ask for the username, such as calling `in.nextLine();` and discarding the data, or by calling `clientinput.skip(clientinput.available());` Try doing this before asking for the username - ie immediately after creating the `Scanner`.

As a follow-on, as you are talking to a Telnet server, I would definately encourage you to follow the advise of @StephenC - you should be implementing the correct handshaking and data transmission properties of the Telnet specification rather than simply sending Strings through the Socket.

Comment: 1. No, and I use windows.
2. No, I only use the QWERTY keyboard keys (English).

Comment: How about trying point 3 in my edited answer above - maybe the stream is dirty from when it was created.

Comment: If you're using a telnet client to connect to your server, it's possible the initial "dirty input" is the client attempting telnet option negotiations with the server ("will echo" etc.)

Comment: @DavidGelhar - I'd revise that to "highly likely" rather than "possible".  IMO, option 3 is bad advice.  It might work, but it is the wrong way to do this.  Telnet has an open specification, and a client (such as the OP's program) should conform to the specification.

Answer (score 3):

The real problem is that you are treating a telnet server as if it is a socket server that simply sends and receives character data.  It no such thing!

A telnet server implements the telnet protocol as described in [RFC 854](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc854) (updated to support Unicode by [RFC 5198](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5198)).  The main RFC specifies a number of special sequences that are sent by a telnet client or server.

If your client is going to work properly against any telnet server, it needs to implement the protocol properly.  The workaround suggested by WATTO might work in this case ... but you may find that this (or another) telnet server inserts these "strange characters" at other points.  In fact, they are not "strange characters" at all. They are well-defined elements of the telnet protocol, and they MEAN something.

Comment: I do totally agree @StephenC - it is almost certainly part of the telnet protocol and I seem to have overlooked the fact that this user was attempting to communicate with a telnet server. My response was indeed an attempt to 'alleviate' the problem the user encountered, rather than a more correct answer like yours. I'm not sure what the user is attempting to do with his Socket, but I would definitely encourage the correct implementation of the telnet protocol rather than simply sending Strings through the Socket.